# Central Admin Site blank after I restore my database

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade

We are upgrading from 3.o to SharePoint 2010. We have restored content database.  We are able to connect to our sharepoint sites however when we connect to SharePoint Central Administration there are no categories listed on the homepage. `For example application management, monitoring, security, system settings, configuration wizard are missing.`

You can see the resources link on right hand side but that is all. Any ideas? -

Comment: could you please share screen shot? also how you migrate the databases? did you migrate the central admin db as well?